# Pandas Groupby or Pivot Table with multiindex and partial sums

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot, multi-index

I have a dataset that looks a bit like this:

```
Miami     , Florida   , 4, B
Miami     , Florida   , 3, A
Tampa     , Florida   , 2, A
San Jose  , California, 5, B
Sacramento, California, 7, C
```

and would like to produce a multi-indexed table, that contains sum rows:

```
sum                21  B
    California     12  C
        Sacramento  7  C
        San Jose    5  B
    Florida         9  A
        Miami       7  B
        Tampa       2  A
```

Can this be done with pandas groupby or pivot tables? Or do I need something different for that?

I'm really more interested in the sum rows than the aggregate function for the 'public vote' letters. I understand that I could create additional rows with `city := "_sum_"+state` add the the values are the agg values. the question is whether this can be achieved without workarounds